# Is it possible to sync gmail record automatically to the application built by app maker?

Tags: google-app-maker

I am planning to build a task tracking system, so I am wondering if it is possible to sync gmail's communication between users to the system automatically?

Thank you all and I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Usually it's better to store state of the task in DB. And send emails with links to the app where the state can be changed.

But answering your original question:
You can use Apps Script's [Gmail Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/) to access user's emails. But mails can be accesses while the user is using your app only.